# PHP - symfony2 - Getting error when checking whether Session is set or not

Tags: php, session, symfony-2.4

Problem - I want to check whether the session is set or not in the '__construct' of a 'Controller', but i am getting the following error -

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead)

The following is the code snippet which is in my '__construct' -

```
function __construct() {

   $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
   $session = $request->getSession();
   if(!isset($session->get('id'))){
     $this->redirect('UserAuthBundle:Auth:login.html.twig');
   }

}
```

If I use '!= null' instead of '!isset' its giving me an error as following -

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Is there any other alternative way so that this can be implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory; you can't use `isset` on the result of a function call. It even gives you an alternative

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error message provides a solution

Comment: even i use '!=null' its giving me the error which i have stated above. Is there any other alternative way so that i can accompolish this

Comment: Why don't you first check `$session`?

Comment: And the second question: why do you create `$request` from globals instead of injecting it to the controller action methods?

Comment: If this is a proper controller, you can just use `$this->get('session')`

Comment: @phil can you please come up with the code so that it will be very helpfull for me

Comment: I don't think you should be doing this in a controller constructor.

Comment: Do you extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` with your controller?

Comment: Is there any other way so as to check whether the session data is set or not? If its not set then I want to redirect to login page

Comment: @user1696621 if you really extend Symfony's controller class, then just do `$session = $this->get('session');` in your controller action and work with `$session` object then. Don't do what you are doing in the constructor, it is all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

**Warning**

`isset()` only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.